# Nginx location block rule

Tags: nginx, redirect

`location  /webapi/activate/register {
  rewrite ^/webapi/activate/register(.*)$ $scheme://test.example.com/help/woobe$1;
}`

Will this serve both my need of redirecting users with /register? and /register/?. So say a user "A" puts in the URL /webapi/activate/register? and user "B" uses /webapi/activate/register/? . Will the above example satisfy my need. If No, how can i achieve this.

Comment: So this will send user A to ".../woobe?" and user B to "...woobe/?",right? Is this your intention?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to enter the location block successfully and might do fine with rewrite as well. But if the problem is trailing slash, you can remove that as,

```
rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
```